# Displaying adsense ads with dynamic information

Tags: html, adsense, ads

I want to display ads on ad sense from dynamic content, I.E call an API and send in some keywords to get ads, is this possible?

E.G:

```
Adsense.GetAdsForKeywords("car, subaru, auckland");
```

Or failing that, have some mark up on the page for words to be used with adsense E.G

```
<span class="adsense-words">car,subaru,auckland</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't choose keywords for your ads , Google automatically choose ads for your site based on the text content of your site, as mentioned here [Link](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32844) .

but you can do **Section Targeting** , to emphasize the content between the section, you can use it as folows

```
<!-- google_ad_section_start -->

your preferred content goes here, google will emphasize more on this section, you can put your keywords span here

<span class="adsense-words">car,subaru,auckland</span>

<!-- google_ad_section_end -->
```

[reference on section targeting](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23168)

Comment: Thanks, Hopefully this is weighted heavily